# videos to show in thumbnails?

Tags: android, text, video-thumbnails

Im new to android..
How to show video thumbnail with text in a ListView row?

I have stored a set of youtube url in my database(server). By using AsyncTask i retrieved the url's and stored in an array string...
Now in onPostExecute method..How to display this array video url's in list view with text??

How to implement this??

```
class LoadFiles extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Focusarea.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Videos. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
      protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_geturl, "GET", params);           
    Log.d("All Groups: ", json.toString());
    try {
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        System.out.println("Success");
        if (success == 1) {
            System.out.println("Success");   
            groups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GROUP);
            System.out.println("Result Success+++"+groups);
            for (int i = 0; i < groups.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = groups.getJSONObject(i);
                String intro = c.getString(TAG_INTRO);
                System.out.println("Checking ::"+intro);
                                vid.add(intro);
                System.out.println("VIDEOS LINK" + vid);
                if(intro!=null && intro!=""){
                    videoUrl=intro;
                }else {
                    showAlert();
                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
        System.out.println("Error "+e.toString());
            }
        return null;
          }
               protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting VIDEOS
        pDialog.dismiss();  
        vid=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(vid));
           // how to implement here...
                }
             }
```

Comment: I do not see anywhere you're getting a direct URL pointing to a thumbnail image. Do you have any? If no, I suggest you take a look at YoutubeAndroidPlayer library, or google youtube v3 library. The former allows you to create a thumbnail view with just video ID, but requires download everytime, the latter is more to manual work, use it to grab a URL of thumbnail image, then save it into your SD card for display.

Comment: In String intro im getting the url from database and stored in vid array ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) AsyncTasks in which the image is downloaded first, stored into a cache, and then displayed on the onPostExecute method. The image is obtained from the cache subsequently.

2) Nostra's [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

3) Fedor's [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList). And;

4) Novoda's [ImageLoader](https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader).

Comment: im having my video url in an array how to implement in onpostexecute to display the list of videos...

Comment: If you want to display images on AsyncTask in listview then you have to one of above method

Comment: that code in my case its not working so i didn't accept..Still i didn't yet to solve...